# Setting X-axis (Category axis) and Y-axis (Value axis)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have an Excel sheet with some data and a graph. I use the following code, setting the minimum and maximum value for the Value (Y) axis. This works fine:

```
Dim cht As ChartObject

    MaxChartNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(totalWeights(1, 1), 0)
    MinChartNumber = totalWeights(daysToPip, 8)
    If totalWeights(daysToPip, 9) < MinChartNumber Then
        MinChartNumber = totalWeights(daysToPip, 9)
    End If
    MinChartNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(MinChartNumber, 0)

    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinChartNumber
        cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxChartNumber
    Next cht
```

I would like to have a minimum and maximum for the Category (X) as well. So I added:

```
For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinChartNumber
    cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxChartNumber
    cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 1
    cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = daysToPip
Next cht
```

This throws an error:

[image: error screen]

What is the correct procedure to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Stupid how blind you can be... chosen for X axis based on dates. Now it works fine.

[image: screen]